# Prove that if A and B are mutually exclusive then $P(A)\leq P(B^c)$.

Tags: probability

Suppose $\textbf{P}(A\cap B) = 0$. Prove $\textbf{P}(A) \leq \textbf{P}(B^{c})$ using the axioms of probability.

I know the axioms are:

1. $\textbf{P}(A)\geq 0$.
2. $\textbf{P}(\Omega) = 1$.
3. If A and B are disjoint, $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$.

I've tried messing around with each of these axioms to end up with the proof statement, but haven't been able to get to it. Does anybody know how to prove this using the axioms?

Thanks

Comment: That said, I think you need to elaborate a bit more.  If you are talking about continuous probabilities, say, we can have possible events of $0$ probability...so in that case $P(A\cap B)=0$ does not imply that $A\cap B = \emptyset$.  Perhaps you meant to exclude this case somehow?  Or perhaps "subset" here just means that $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)$?

Comment: Just to stress my point:  suppose that we are speaking of a single draw from a  uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  Let $A$ be the event "you draw $\frac 13$".  And let $B$ be the event "you draw a number $<\frac 12$".  then $P(A\cap B)=0$ because $P(A)=0$.   But $A$ actually is a subset of $B$...$A\cap B^c=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 4):

$$P(A)=P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B^c)= P(A\cap B^c)\leq P(B^c)$$
The first equality uses $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$, and Axiom 3. (union of disjoints sets).

The last inequality follows from the more general $X\subset Y \implies P(X)\leq P(Y)$, which is a consequence of $Y=X\cup(Y\setminus X)$ and Axiom 3.

Comment: I think OP would benefit from an explication of each of your $=$s and $\leq$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$P(B^\complement)-P(A)=1-P(B)-P(A)=1-P(A\cup B)\ge0,$$where the second $=$ uses $P(A\cap B)=0$.